# How can I create an AppBar in Metro that works in a WebView?

Tags: windows-8, webview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, appbar

So I got a normal AppBar to work in a C# metro app, but the problem is I need the app to display an html page. I create a WebView that takes up 100% of the width and height of the page, and by doing so, the AppBar doesn't show up anymore on right clicks and edge swipes. Is there a way for the AppBar to work with such a WebView in place?

--Resolved--

What I ended up doing was adding a 1px border around the WebView so that swipes could be detected. Since what I included in my WebView dynamically changes with time, WebViewBrush didn't work out for me. Instead I just shrunk the size of the WebView when the AppBar is opened and then expanded it when it was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not trying to steal Filip's answer, but I think a few more details are necessary to fully answer the question.

Even with a WebView running full-screen, the AppBar tries to show itself when you right-click or swipe. You can prove this by subscribing to the **AppBar.Opened** event. What's interesting is that the AppBar appears to somehow know it's obscured and automatically closes itself. Even if it didn't close itself, you wouldn't be able to see it because it's obscured under the WebView.

Filip had the right idea about hiding the WebView and using WebViewBrush while the AppBar is open. You can find a good example of doing that here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush.aspx

As for when to swap between WebView and WebViewBrush, I'd simply do it on AppBar.Opened and reverse it on AppBar.Closed. AppBar is light dismiss, meaning as soon as you tap anywhere outside of it's client area it will close.

One last word of advice: In my testing it seemed that the swipe gesture was getting swallowed sometimes. That problem seemed to go away when I put a 1 pixel boarder on top and bottom of the WebView. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Does it work when the user right click on the mouse to display the appbar? In my app the swipe gesture is working but when using the mouse the appbars open and close immediately

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the WebView while displaying XAML UI on top of it and use the WebViewBrush instead.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, the 1px border can help with ensuring the top/bottom swipe is honored for the AppBar. However, similar to @matthieu I was still having issues getting the AppBar to open reliably when using the mouse and right-click method.

The issue was that I included the  XAML element as a peer to the WebView, rather than as a parent as the [MSDN reference for AppBar.Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.closed.aspx) suggests:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Margin="100,20,100,20">
    <Grid>
        <WebView x:Name="contentView" Source="http://www.contoso.com"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="contentViewRect"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

If I apply the border this way, the AppBar also reliably opens with the mouse.

One last thing to note is that using a `BorderBrush="Transparent"` works fine as well, so you don't have to actually see the ugly border. My final XAML was something like:

```
<Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <Grid>
        <WebView x:Name="WebView"></WebView>
        <Rectangle x:Name="RectWebViewBrush"></Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```